# What is the type of this connector?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Can someone tell me what the type of connector is??[image]

Comment: A picture or pictures with more detail?

Comment: a larger version of this connector is used for power supply circuits and is called an "anderson" connector.

Comment: Anderson power pole connectors are of a different construction, but similar in that they are rectangular. Anderson connectors are designed to couple to each other and are interchangeable in polarity, unlike the pictured connectors.

Comment: Did you try Google Images?  Specifically it is a DuPont 2.54mm female single connector.  [DuPont](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DuPont-Single-Row-2-54mm-Connector-Housing-Female-Crimps-1-10-12-20-Pin-/232414804730)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited information in the photo, I used "female breadboard jumper wire" as a preliminary search. This resulted in many returns, all of which appear as in the image. Additionally, the term "Dupont" arose. More searching results in returns for single pin Dupont connectors as well as multiple pin connectors, often found on computer mainboards for USB connections and similar.